# iOS: How do I make my UITextfield highlight when tapped?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Do I have to do this with code or is there something in the inspector that I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike `UIButton`, a `UITextField` does not have a highlighted state. If you want to change the color of the textfield when it receives focus, you can use the `UITextFieldDelegate`'s 
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

This will be called when the control first receives focus. From there you can change the background and/or text color. Once focus leaves the control, you can use 
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` 
to reset the colors.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` instead of `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` & `textFieldShouldEndEditing` ? OP wants to highlight the field, not modify/check if the textField should remain in edit mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2, you can use the delegate functions like below,

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate{
    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        self.delegate = self // SETTING DELEGATE TO SELF
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() // setting a highlight color
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // setting a default color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to be able to use other delegate functions in you ViewController, I recommend you to add this:

```
override weak var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? {
    didSet {
        if delegate?.isKindOfClass(YourTextField) == false {
            // Checks so YourTextField (self) doesn't set the textFieldDelegate when assigning self.delegate = self 
            textFieldDelegate = delegate
            delegate = self
        }
    }
}

// This delegate will actually be your public delegate to the view controller which will be called in your overwritten functions
private weak var textFieldDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate?

class YourTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        textFieldDelegate?.textFieldDidBeginEditing?(textField)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textFieldDelegate?.textFieldDidBeginEditing?(textField)
    }
}
```

This way your view controller doesn't need to know that you have overwritted the delegate and you can implement UITextFieldDelegate functions in your view controller.

```
let yourTextField = YourTextField()
yourTextField.delegate = self
```